# Problem with bone disconnecting during animation

Tags: animation, bones, drivers, pose-mode

I have difficulty articulating my thought, so please be patient with me.  I am having issue of child bone disconnecting from parent bone eventhough they are "connected" during animation/posing (ref pic1).  I have tried re-constructing the bone and drivers, but the issue persists.

What are the causes and possible solution for this one?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: I have been trying to fix the problem.  The problem reoccures when I add copy rotation for IK or drivers for FK/IK switches on reconstructed bones.  Is it bug?  Have 2.8 fix the problem?  I am still using 2.79.  btw.

Comment: Nothing can be done.  So, I just copy everything and paste it in a new blender file and we work the bones.  And it is fixed lol.